# How to create a Restful service with java tomcat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

I want to create a Restful web-service which will generate JSON output...
in that it should contains some image urls like following and also number of json arrays and json objects,..

```
    { 
    "worldpopulation": 
    [
         {
         "rank":1,"country":"China",
         "population":"1,354,040,000",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png"
         }, 

         {
         "rank":2,"country":"India",
         "population":"1,210,193,422",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png"
         }, 

         {
         "rank":3,"country":"United States",
         "population":"315,761,000",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/unitedstates.png"
         }

    ] 
    }
```

SO that i can use it later in a mobile device,...

Comment: There is the first bug. Population is a number not a string.

Comment: ho god already this is working sir and this is the link i tried,... and its not a bug,... here is the [link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt) of the data,.. I need to create a data like this,.. and some stupids are giving down rank,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is your Google down!!!** There are a lots of good stuffs available in Google related with REST web-service.

Anyway Take a look at this stuff

**[Building a Simple RESTful Web Service to produce JSON using Jersey](http://www.jeeconsultant.com/sites/jeeconsultant.nsf/docs/Building%20a%20Simple%20RESTful%20Web%20Service%20to%20produce%20JSON%20using%20Jersey)**

**[Developing REST Web Services in Eclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webservices_rest/)**

For creating a JSON see this example
Say you want to create a JSON as shown below

```
 { 
    "worldpopulation": 
    [
         {
         "rank":1,"country":"China",
         "population":"1,354,040,000",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png"
         }, 

         {
         "rank":2,"country":"India",
         "population":"1,210,193,422",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png"
         }, 

         {
         "rank":3,"country":"United States",
         "population":"315,761,000",
         "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/unitedstates.png"
         }

    ] 
 }
```

The java code for creating the above JSON is as given below

```
JSONObject jsonobj=new JSONObject();
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray();
HashMap rows=new HashMap();
rows.put("rank","1");
rows.put("country","China");
rows.put("population","1,354,040,000");
rows.put("flag","http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png");
obj.put(rows);

rows=new HashMap();
rows.put("rank","2");
rows.put("country","India");
rows.put("population","1,210,193,422");
rows.put("flag","http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png");
obj.put(rows);

rows=new HashMap();
rows.put("rank","3");
rows.put("country","United States");
rows.put("population","315,761,000");
rows.put("flag","http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/unitedstates.png");

jsonobj.put("worldpopulation", obj);

System.out.println(jsonobj.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

The first quick thing you might do to get started is Googleing for a tomcat "hello world" and change it to return your json as an hard-coded string.

My first google result is this link http://www-inf.it-sudparis.eu/~nguyen_n/teaching_assistant/servlet-jsp/helloworld-tomcat

There you can change the lines like:

```
out.println("<HTML>");
```

to be like

```
out.println("{ 
                \"worldpopulation\": 
                [
                 {\"
            ....");
```